# ReactJS: Turn object into array and render

Tags: reactjs, meteor, ecmascript-6

So, my component receives an object from a parent component and the object looks like this:

```
{ 
  _id: Data.now(), // MongoDB database
  name: "",
  description: "",
  image: "images/image.jpg",
  type: "image"
}
```

In my child component, I want to take this data and make an input for each one so I can change the values and then save the new data.

Updated Answer (es6 class):

```
constructor(props) {
  super();
  this.state = {
    fieldGroups: []
  }

  this.parseProps = this.parseProps.bind(this);
}

componentWillMount() {
  this.parseProps(this.props);
}

componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
  this.parseProps(nextProps);
}

parseProps(props) {
  var fieldsArray = [];
  var content = props.content;
  Object.keys(content).map((field,index) => {
    if (field === 'type') {
      let fieldObj = {};
      fieldObj.field = field;
      fieldObj.value = content[field];
      fieldObj.key   = props.content._id + field;
      fieldsArray.push(fieldObj);
    }
  });
  this.setState({
    fieldGroups: fieldsArray
  });
}

render() {
  return (
    {
      this.state.fieldGroups.map((field) => {
       if (field.field === "type") { 
         return ( html element specific to type )
       } else {
         return ( a different html element )
       }
     })
    }
  )
}
```

So now I can separate my components in the sense of letting the child component decide which fields to show the user. Thanks DanneManne

Comment: Hard to tell from this incomplete example. Can you show more code for this component? Is it a class? Did you implement the constructor correctly? https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function `componentDidMount` is just as the named indicates, only being called once after the component has mounted. But if the parent component is re-rendering the child component with updated properties, then the child is already mounted and that function is not being called again.

Another thing to note is that the purpose of `componentDidMount` is that you can fetch data from the actual DOM if you want to look at things like `offsetWidth` or `offsetHeight` of another element, but if you are not using the DOM at all, then your are probably better of using `componentWillMount` to avoid additional manipulation of the DOM, since that is usually the most time consuming part.

What you are missing is the combined usage of `componentWillMount` together with `componentWillReceiveProps` which is a function that is called every time the parent is re-rendering the child.

The pattern I usually go with is:

```
  constructor(props){
    super();
    this.parseProps = this.parseProps.bind(this);
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    this.parseProps(this.props);
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    this.parseProps(nextProps);
  }

  // === Parsing Props
  //
  //  Takes care of component specific adjustment of
  //  props that parent components does not need to
  //  know about. An example can be sorting or grouping
  //  of records.
  //
  parseProps(props) {
    this.setState({
      // key: props.key
    });
  }
```

So the logic that you currently have in `componentDidMount` can be moved into the `parseProps` function.

Comment: Hey, I got it working, I'll update the answer, as the solution took a bit of trial. Also, I might be adding things unnecessarily.